# How do i send arguments from C# windows form to GDB console?

Tags: c#, gdb

I'm trying to make an app that tests a buffer overflow through a C# windows form. For that, I need to open gdb from a C# process and pass the following commands:

- cd C:\users\user\desktop
- file file.exe
- disas main
- run file
- insert input

The following code does start gdb.exe, but unfortunately it does not change the working directory.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "gdb.exe"; 
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"cd C:\users\andrei\desktop";
p.Start();
```

The GDB console output looks like:

```
cd: No such file or directory.
C:\users\andrei\desktop: Permission denied.
```

So, i have 3 problems now:

- How do I make it change the working path?
- How do I send the other commands as arguments?
- How do I get the console output back C# in a label/textbox?

Thank you.

Comment: Please do some research first and not ask 3 problems in one question. 1 - check MSDN for StartInfo, 2/3 - should be dup of million other "how to run command line program and redirect input/output" questions.

Comment: Well, the GDB console doesn't seem to have the same behavior as a normal console.